# What kind of parser should I use in Python to match a text against a boolean condition

Tags: python, parsing, yacc

Let's say I have a text that reads

```
John likes apple, banana and grapes
```

and I have a boolean expression something like

```
((banana & apple) & (!orange)) || (peach)
```

which basically means that the text should ((contain both the words "banana" and the word "apple") and (should not contain "orange")) or (contains the word "peach").

Applying the above boolean logic to the text we need to get the result as True (because it indeed contains banana and apple and does not contain the word orange.

What is an easy way to implement such boolean rules in Python? Is there a framework that can take a chunk of text and an expression and evaluate it? The expressions can be written in a way to satisfy the requirements of the framework if necessary.

So far, I am parsing the Python text using a simple code that will keep track of the paranthesis and so on which is not so efficient and does not provide an opportunity to explore more flexible expressions.

Thanks

Comment: I would use regex.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer regex isn't exactly the right tool here, though I'm sure you could make it work....

Comment: @AdamSmith I don't know if there would be a faster way to do it but to me it sounds like a problem that could be solved with a few regex expressions and regular logic.

Comment: I have used regex by basic parsing of the expression but that doesnt give you the flexibility of adding more complex expressions and the code is really not maintainable.

Comment: Do you also need OR?

Comment: @RamazanPolat yes I will need to be able to specify OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you want to do it by providing a text to be parsed but I have this in mind:

```
class String(str):
    def __call__(self, *args):
        s = str(self)
        for arg in args:
            if arg not in s:
                return False
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s1 = String("John likes apple, banana and grapes")
    print(s1("apple", "banana") and not s1("orange"))  # True
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good start but I would like to specify the expressions in an external file and make it completely flexible. I stumbled upon this btw - https://github.com/jackdied/boolmatch

Comment: As you have provided an answer that shows the right direction even if the rule has to be hardcoded, I am going to accept it.